# C: Counting the number of Upper/Lower case chars out of a file

Tags: c, file, uppercase, lowercase

Well I'm trying to read a text from a file and then write to another one how many upper and lower case characters there are, as well as how many numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p;
    int caps, low, num, i;
   caps = low = num = 0;

    FILE *fin, *fout;

    fin = fopen("input.txt","r");
    fout = fopen("output.txt","w");

    if (fin == NULL)
    {
       printf("FILE ERROR\n");
       return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("BABE THIS WORKS\n");

    i=0;

    while(fscanf(fin, "%s", p) != EOF)
      {
              if(p[i] >= 'a' && p[i] <= 'z')                
                         low++;         
              if(p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] <= 'Z')                
                         caps++;  
              if(p[i] >= '0' && p[i] <= '9')                
                         num++;                               
      }

    fprintf(fout,"Lower: %d, Caps: %d, Numbers: %d", low, caps, num);

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

 system("pause");   
 return 0;   
}
```

However, when I run this, it just "crashes" and doesn't write anything in the output.txt file.

What did I miss?

Comment: Could you share what you've learned from running this in a debugger?

Comment: You never allocate memory to `p`. You need to do that before you assign values to it in you while loop.

Comment: @Katie it's AppCrash i guess

Comment: @Katie OMG this is the best way ever to say "Use a debugger!". May I save your phase for future use?

Comment: @Coursal - dont be silly. Dont guess, _actually run it in a debugger_.

Comment: You checked that you opened the input file OK; you didn't check that you  opened the output file.  Always check every `fopen()`.

Comment: Also, you only check the first character of each line, which is probably not what you are intended to do.

Comment: @David C. Rankin You're right, it does run, but in the output.txt it says "Lower: 0, Caps: 0, Numbers: 0"

Comment: `int p;` .. `while((p=fgetc(fin)) != EOF)`.. `if(p >= 'a' &&...`

Comment: @Coursal Look at the updated comment.

Comment: `int p`, then `while(fscanf(fin, "%c", &p) != EOF)` should fix the problem. In that case, `while ((p = fgetc(fin)) != EOF)` (duh... smacks self) is probably a better loop condition. The faster alternative is to allocate enough memory to hold the entire file, read it all at once with `fread`, then assign a pointer to the first char and loop through the block of memory rather than reading from a file. (don't forget to get rid of `p[i]` and use simply `p` in the interior of the loop.

Comment: I guess you should allocate memory to your `int *` (do you have a segfault?).

Plus I think you should read your file as chars if you only use ASCII chars. Not as int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are comparing *characters*, the simplest case for your read is to use *character-oriented* input. The library provides several *character-oriented* input functions, (e.g. `getchar()` (reading from `stdin`) or `getc` and `fgetc` reading from a `FILE* stream`). This prevents having to step through any array checking each char after your read.

A short example using your approach would be as follows. The only tweak was to include a ternary operator that either read/writes to the filenames given as arguments to the program (or from the default `stdin` and `stdout` if no filenames are given). It just prevents hardcoding the filenames in the file. To use the program on `input.txt` and `output.txt`, simply call the program as `./programname input.txt output.txt`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int p, caps, low, num;
    p = caps = low = num = 0;

    FILE *fin, *fout;

    /* read from filename argv[1] (default: stdin), 
       write to  filename argv[2] (default: stdout) */
    fin  = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    fout = argc > 2 ? fopen (argv[2], "w") : stdout;

    if (fin == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "input file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (fout == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "output file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((p = fgetc (fin)) != EOF)
    {
        if ('a' <= p && p <= 'z') low++;         
        if ('A' <= p && p <= 'Z') caps++;  
        if ('0' <= p && p <= '9') num++;                               
    }

    fprintf (fout, "\n Lower: %d, Caps: %d, Numbers: %d\n\n", low, caps, num);

    if (fin  != stdin)  fclose(fin);
    if (fout != stdout) fclose(fout);

    //system("pause");   

    return 0;   
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Output (reading/writing to default stdin/stdout)**

```
$ ./bin/countltrs <../dat/captnjack.txt

 Lower: 47, Caps: 12, Numbers: 0
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The only [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) guaranteed contiguous character representations are the digits `'0'` - `'9'`.  **5.2.1 Character sets** *In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
value of each character after
`0`
in the above 
list of decimal digits shall be one greater than
the value of the previous.*  Neither `'a'`-'`'z'` nor `'A`'-`'Z'` are guaranteed to represented contiguously.